# Position vector of robot arm

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

[image]

This is related to robotics mathematics. I am having a hard time understanding how they get the position vectors and since z2 is movable, z2 should not be a 0 in the z -column(last column) of position vector right?

Comment: base frame has $z$-axis pointing outwards from the plane of the screen

Answer (score 0):

The components $~x_0~,y_0~,z_0~$  to point $~m_2~$ are

$$\vec R_{m2}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} d_{{2}}-\frac 12\,L_{{2}}\\ L_{
{1}}\\ 0\end {array} \right] 
$$

and the transformation matrix is:

$$\mathbf S_z= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \theta \right) &-\sin \left( 
\theta \right) &0\\  \sin \left( \theta \right) &\cos
 \left( \theta \right) &0\\  0&0&1\end {array}
 \right] 
$$